# Joining two tables in codeginiter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables that i want to join & show the name of user's role. here's the situation

My 2 tables are users_mlh & user_roles_mlh

on the role column of users_mlh table i'm storing the ID of user role, user_roles_mlh contains the name  & id of user role. what i want to do is show the name of the user role in my view.

my tables as follows.

[image: Screen1]

i have tried this in my model

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user_roles_mlh');
$this->db->join('users_mlh', 'users_mlh.role = user_roles_mlh.id');
$this->db->where('users_mlh.role = user_roles_mlh.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
```

but from above i get something like this

[image: https://s4.postimg.org/ot5nyr1hp/Untitled_122.jpg]

at the moment it lists all user level not the role of each individual user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to write separate query for getting role name. Join Roles table when you fetching users data..

```
$this->db->select('users_mlh.*,user_roles_mlh.role_type');
$this->db->from('users_mlh');
$this->db->join('user_roles_mlh', 'user_roles_mlh.id = users_mlh.role');

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 : If you Directly want to Access all data without using where condition

```
  $this->db->select( "*" );
  $this->db->from( 'users_mlh' );
  $this->db->join('user_roles_mlh', 'user_roles_mlh.id = users_mlh.role');
```

Case 2: With Where Condition and specific column data

```
   $this->db->select( 'user_roles_mlh.role_type,users_mlh.name' );
  $this->db->from( 'users_mlh' );
  $this->db->join('user_roles_mlh', 'user_roles_mlh.id = users_mlh.role');
   $this->db->where('users_mlh.id =',1);
```

And finally get the results by

```
  $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use your tables, you should have the following request:

```
SELECT users_mlh.*, JOIN user_roles_mlh.role_type
FROM users_mlh -- list all users
  LEFT JOIN user_roles_mlh -- and joind by roles
    ON users_mlh.role = user_roles_mlh.id -- condition for joining
```

With this request, you will have all your users, with the role text associated.

So, if this request works, use the same logic on your ORM

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate your help